# Add Neos Fusion rendered markup snippet to the elasticseach index

Tags: elasticsearch, fusion, neoscms

I asked myself if it is possible to customize the indexing of the Nodes so that we can put a rendered markup snippet to the node in Elasticsearch. So that we have in ES a property that contains the rendered Fusion snippet.

Is that already possible? I know that we can create custom indexer.
https://github.com/Flowpack/Flowpack.ElasticSearch.ContentRepositoryAdaptor#indexing-configuration-per-property

Maybe that would be a Solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use https://github.com/punktDe/outofbandrendering for rendering content via eel and then put this into your elasticsearch index.